# OpenGL: Take screenshot of screen and transform (shrink) it, then draw that on a portion of the screen

Tags: android, opengl-es, transform, screenshot

I want to use OpenGL for Android to take the screen (make "continuous" screenshots), make it smaller vertically, then paint it back to leave a black bar at the bottom of the display.

Basically:

1. Read pixels
2. Transform (shrink the screen vertically)
3. Paint back the shrunk screenshot on the display.
4. Repeat 1.-3. continuously.

How can I do this? The bottom line is that I want to have space for some other stuff at the bottom of the screen while still not missing something underneath what I want to display (think the soft home buttons in Android).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds insanely expensive. I'd really try just to render it at the correct size in the first place.

Use glScissor to limit the region of the screen to stop drawing outside of that, and glViewport to correct the transform behaviour.

Comment: Do you know of any way to limit the launcher (and all other apps) screen in Android (so that apps cant draw in that region)?

Comment: Globally? No - tends to be difficult without hacking the operating system (e.g. lying about the the window size).